# Find the number of ways to arrange 8 students with restriction

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

8 students are arranged in a row. How many ways to arrange them if 3 particular students must be separated?

Comment: you mean always seperated? and because this is a naive question, you mean that each time there is always one guy between them right?

Comment: @mayer_vietoris yes, always one or more guy between them

Comment: I would focus my efforts on how many 3-subsets of the 8(?) seats in the row satisfy the not-adjacent seating restriction.  (It should probably be clarified that the row has exactly eight seats.)

Comment: An approach I would use is to compute:

(# ways to seat 8 students in a row without restrictions) - (# ways to set the 8 students so as to violate the constraint explicitly).

The number of ways to violate the constraint explicitly (i.e., have at least 2 of the 3 students $s_1, s_2, s_3$ sit together) is the "Inclusion-Exclusion Principle":

(#  ways to seat $s_1, s_2$ together) + ( # ways to seat $s_2, s_3$ together) - (# ways to seat $s_{1}, s_{2}, s_{3}) together).

For a general flowchart of this approach, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrfA8mKOIjI.

Answer (score 2):

Select one of the $5$ non-particular students who will stand to the left of the rightmost particular student, and one of the remaining $4$ non-particular students who will stand to the right of the leftmost particular student. Permute the remaining $6$ students in $6!$ ways and place the two preselected non-particular students as planned, for a total of $5\cdot4\cdot6!=14400$ arrangements.

Comment: I do understand your above argument in general, however we have 3 "particular" students, so if we permute 6 students that means that it is possible to end up in some permutations with the 3rd "particular student" beside one of the other 2 right? and we want them seperate.

Comment: @mayer_vietoris: Yes -- that's what the two preselected non-particular students are for. The three particular students may be next to each other after you permute the $6$, but when you then place the first preselected non-particular student to the left of the rightmost particular student and the second one to the right of the leftmost particular student, the particular students will be separated.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*:Find the no. of ways 2 particular students will be **always together** and twice the no. of ways 3 particular students will be **always together**.Subtract the 2nd from 1st.Subtract the result from the no. of all possible permutations.

Comment: We also need to remove any 2 of the particular students together. But it's a good start.

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: but there are some ways when two of the three particular students are standing together,while the remaining one separated from the two

Comment: Is it correct now?Someone please downvote if it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use stars to represent the five non-particular students and bars to represent the three particular students.  Then a feasible seating arrangement involves choosing three positions from the six that are either between two stars or at the end.  For instance,
$$
\star | \star \star \star | \star | 
$$
The number of ways to do this is $\binom{6}{3}$.

Now keeping in mind the fact that the stars and bars are individual, distinguishable students, we can permute the stars and bars separately.  Therefore the number of arrangements is
$$
   \binom{6}{3}\cdot 3! \cdot 5! = 14400
$$